# Sharepoint API call takes too much time

Tags: c#, csom, sharepoint-api

I have a Sharepoint API call like this

```
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery
{
    ViewXml = @"<View Scope='Recursive'>
                 <Query>
                 </Query>
             </View>",
    FolderServerRelativeUrl = myFolder.ServerRelativeUrl
};
ListItemCollection Items = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
cntxt.Load(Items, icol => icol.Include(i => i.Folder,

    i => i.Id,
    i => i.File.Name,
    i => i.File.TimeCreated,
    i => i.File.LinkingUrl,
    i => i.File.UniqueId,
    i => i.File.ListItemAllFields));
cntxt.ExecuteQuery();
```

This takes almost 10 seconds to get a response (only 350 items are returned from this call). Is there anything wrong with the way I am querying the data? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: First of all, which version of sharepoint are you targeting ? Online? On-Prem? 13?16?19?
Second of all, do you count the time opening a clientcontext within the 10 seconds?

Comment: @jimas13SHarepointOnline , I had put datetime.now before and after the call to calculate the timespan

Comment: Since it's the online version of SharePoint, unfortunately there's not many ways that you could debug the behaviour of the code segment. I would recommend using VS debugger to view all the code paths and if any other load statements are predefined. In addition, you could use fiddler to see the network traffic generated.

Comment: I assume that the SharePoint csom nugget packages are all up to date. This is the most difficult part in such scenarios, because the csom nugget packages that hide away the API calls are provided as is.